# what happens when string is implicitly converted to int in HIVE?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

When I use hive query data encountered the following such a situation：

`select '6455983054544699410' = 6455983054544699395 ===> true`

So I want to know what happens when string is implicitly converted to int in hive?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sides are being cast to double

```
hive> select '6455983054544699410' =  6455983054544699395;
WARNING: Comparing a bigint and a string may result in a loss of precision.
OK
_c0
true
```

---

```
hive> select cast('6455983054544699410' as double) , cast (6455983054544699395 as double);
OK
_c0 _c1
6.4559830545446994E18   6.4559830545446994E18
```

---

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/plan/ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.java

```
// For now, if a bigint is going to be cast to a double throw an error or warning
      if ((oiTypeInfo0.equals(TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo) && oiTypeInfo1.equals(TypeInfoFactory.longTypeInfo)) ||
          (oiTypeInfo0.equals(TypeInfoFactory.longTypeInfo) && oiTypeInfo1.equals(TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo))) {
        String error = StrictChecks.checkTypeSafety(conf);
        if (error != null) throw new UDFArgumentException(error);
        console.printError("WARNING: Comparing a bigint and a string may result in a loss of precision.");
      } else if ((oiTypeInfo0.equals(TypeInfoFactory.doubleTypeInfo) && oiTypeInfo1.equals(TypeInfoFactory.longTypeInfo)) ||
          (oiTypeInfo0.equals(TypeInfoFactory.longTypeInfo) && oiTypeInfo1.equals(TypeInfoFactory.doubleTypeInfo))) {
        String error = StrictChecks.checkTypeSafety(conf);
        if (error != null) throw new UDFArgumentException(error);
        console.printError("WARNING: Comparing a bigint and a double may result in a loss of precision.");
      }
```